# Use view model property to populate drop down list for

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to avoid using the view bag to populate an `Html.DropDownListFor` and not having the best luck.

I want to pull all the state codes used on a particular SQL table and select the distinct values. Then, I want to use those results to populate the drop down list on the view.

In order to do this I created a `List<SelectListItem>` as a property of my view model. In the controller, I attempt to use a Linq query to load the `List`. This appears to work just fine if I step through the code (I can see that there are 50 entries in the `List` after the query), however when the page loads it throws a `NullReferenceException` pointing to the `DropDownListFor`.

**View Model**

```
public class ZipCodeIndex
{
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Zip Code")]
    public string searchZip { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StateCodes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Effective on this date")]
    public string searchDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string searchState { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Territory")]
    public string newTerritory { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Description")]
    public string newDescription { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("New Effective Date")]
    public string newEffectiveDate { get; set; }

    public ZipCodeIndex() 
    {
        zipCodeTerritory = new List<ZipCodeTerritory>();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
//Set state code drop down list
search.StateCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                        select z.StateCode).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = x,
                            Value = x
                        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

**View**

```
<div id="stateBox">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchState)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.searchState, Model.StateCodes, new { style = "width: 25px;", maxLength = 2 })
    <button type="submit" id="SearchButton">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you might be running into an issue by passing in a `List<SelectListItem>` to your helper. Can you try changing the `StateCodes` property to this: `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateCodes { get; set; }`

Comment: And `model.searchState` isn't null, correct?

Comment: When the page first loads, `model.searchState` is null. It's a search parameter so on the first page load it won't have a value in there.

Comment: @ChrisHardie: Still getting the same error with the `IEnumerable` fix. If the page loads with data, however that goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of the `return` statement in my controller. I had a condition set to determine if this was the initial page load and, if so, simply send the user back to the controller. As such, the return statement was simply `return View()`, so I was not sending back a `Model` object to the view. The following code fixed the problem. (`search` is an instance of my view model)

```
        //Proceed with search
        try
        {
            //Set state code drop down list
            search.StateCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                    select z.StateCode).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = x,
                                        Value = x
                                    }).Distinct().ToList();

            //If search criteria is null page is loading for the first time so send blank view OR
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchZip) &&
                String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchDate) &&
                String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchState))
            {
                return View(search);
            }
```